# AJAX Post failing despite data existing

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I am trying to send some data to my server using an AJAX Post call. However, whenever I run the function containing the ajax call I get a server error. Here is my AJAX call (I am trying to send a string and put it inside json for the purposes of this call):

```
function sendFileName(){
    data_to_send={"name": scriptName};
    data_to_send=JSON.stringify(data_to_send);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/filename',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data_to_send,
        error: function(resp){
            console.log("Oh no...");
            console.log(scriptName);
            console.log(resp);
        },
        success: function(resp){
            console.log('Sent file name!');
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

When I log the scriptName I get it in the console, so the data exists. I'm assuming the issue has to do with the way in which I'm sending it?

Here is the server-side code as well, where when I log the req it shows up as undefined:

```
app.post("/filename", function(req,res) {
  file = req.body.name;
  console.log(file);
});
```

Would really appreciate any help I can get with this!

Comment: What's the server error?

Comment: Specifying the request content type using the contentType property in order to indicate to the server the intent of sending a JSON request. contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: @rawathemant thank you! that seems to have fixed the issue with the req being undefined (it now logs as the correct string), but now I am getting a POST 0 () error ( and it was previously a 500 server error). any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: it could be possible to get a status code of 0 if you have sent an AJAX call and a refresh of the browser was triggered before getting the AJAX response. The AJAX call will be canceled and you will get this status.